# How to create a "CertificateSigningRequest" with apiVersion "certificates.k8s.io/v1" for a webhook

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver

I have a wehook running in my cluster.

I created a certificate and signed it successfully.

certificate configuration:

```
cat > csr.conf <<EOF
[req]
req_extensions = v3_req
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
[req_distinguished_name]
[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = serverAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = s-controller.ns-controller
DNS.2 = s-controller.ns-controller.svc
EOF
```

I them create the certificate as following:

```
openssl genrsa -out server-key.pem 2048
openssl req -new -key server-key.pem -subj "/CN=s-controller.ns-controller.svc" -out server.csr -config csr.conf
```

certificate signing request (`v1beta1`)

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl create -f -
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata:
    name: csr-controller
spec:
    groups:
    - system:authenticated
    request: $(cat server.csr | base64 | tr -d '\n')
    usages:
    - digital signature
    - key encipherment
    - server auth
EOF
```

This worked just fine!

Since I updated my kubernetes version, I get the following warning: `Warning: certificates.k8s.io/v1beta1 CertificateSigningRequest is deprecated in v1.19+, unavailable in v1.22+; use certificates.k8s.io/v1`, I updated the `CertificateSigningRequest` so now it is as following:

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl create -f -
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata:
    name: csr-controller
spec:
    groups:
    - system:authenticated
    request: $(cat server.csr | base64 | tr -d '\n')
    signerName: kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver-client
    usages:
    - digital signature
    - key encipherment
    - client auth
EOF
```

And now the api server fails to connect to my webhook: `Post "https://s-controller.ns-controller.svc:443/mutate?timeout=30s": x509: certificate specifies an incompatible key usage`

I tried updateding the certificate configuration to `extendedKeyUsage = clientAuth` but it didnt help.

Any idea what is the correct `signerName` and configuration to the `certificates.k8s.io/v1` apiVersion

Comment: Have you followed any guide/tutorial while setting up your certs?

Comment: I added the certificate creation to the question

Comment: Client auth for webhook admission plugins were tested with both `clientAuth` and `serverAuth` `ExtendedKeyUsage` keys in CSR. Please try to configure the CSR in the same way and let me know if it helps. [Here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/d15dba7e8bff943d91ba6f58fcb0dfefa357a7f1/staging/src/k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/util/webhook/gencerts.sh#L40) is a reference.

Comment: Ok, what `signerName` should I use?

Comment: Which `caBundle` you have put in your `WebhookConfiguration` (`webhooks.clientConfig.caBundle` field) it's important to know before I answer your question ;)

Comment: I use the `certificate-authority-data` as following: `CA_BUNDLE=$(kubectl config view --raw --minify --flatten -o jsonpath='{.clusters[].cluster.certificate-authority-data}')`
Then I create a `MutatingWebhookConfiguration` configuration and add the bundle in the `clientConfig` scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't managed to create a `CertificateSigningRequest` as I wished, **HOWEVER** I bypassed the issue by create my own CA as following:

First, I edited my certificate configurations file so it will include a `commonName` and currect `extendedKeyUsage` :

```
cat > csr.conf <<EOF
[req]
req_extensions = v3_req
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
prompt = no
[req_distinguished_name]
CN = s-controller.ns-controller.svc
[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = clientAuth, serverAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = s-controller.ns-controller
DNS.2 = s-controller.ns-controller.svc
EOF
```

Generate CA certificate (notice the `-days 365`)

```
openssl genrsa -out ca.key 2048
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key ca.key -days 365 -out ca.crt -subj "/CN=admission_ca"
```

Generate tls key and certificdate

```
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr -config csr.conf
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 365 -extensions v3_req -extfile csr.conf
```

Create a kubernetes tls secret for the webhook

```
kubectl create secret tls webhook-tls --cert=server.crt --key=server.key
```

Set the `CA_BUNDLE`

```
export CA_BUNDLE=$(cat ca.crt | base64 | tr -d '\n')
```

Remove all generated files

```
rm ca.crt 
rm ca.key 
rm server.key
rm server.csr
rm server.crt
```

In my webhhok, I have a `volume` `volumeMount`:

volume:

```
volumes:
- name: tls-vol
    secret:
      secretName: webhook-tls
```

volumeMount:

```
volumeMounts:
- name: tls-vol
  mountPath: /etc/webhook/certs
  readOnly: true
```

And the comantainer `args`

```
args:
- -tlsCertFile=/etc/webhook/certs/tls.crt
- -tlsKeyFile=/etc/webhook/certs/tls.key
```

Answer (score 2):

In your old CertificateSigningRequest yaml you were using *server auth* as one of the key usages but, in latest one you changed it to *client auth* . the cert needed by webhook need to be signed with server auth key and signerName should be kubernetes.io/kubelet-serving . So update your files as follows to avoid the issue :

csr.conf

```
 cat > csr.conf <<EOF
 [req]
 req_extensions = v3_req
 distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
 prompt = no
 [req_distinguished_name]
 CN = s-controller.ns-controller.svc
 [ v3_req ]
 basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
 keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
 extendedKeyUsage = clientAuth, serverAuth
 subjectAltName = @alt_names
 [alt_names]
 DNS.1 = s-controller.ns-controller
 DNS.2 = s-controller.ns-controller.svc
 EOF
```

Generate csr with subject.organization as "system:nodes"

```
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
openssl req -new -key server.key -subj "/CN=system:node:s-contoller.ns-controller.svc /OU="system:nodes" /O=system:nodes" -out $server.csr -config csr.conf
```

csr-for-webhook.yaml

```
cat <<EOF | kubectl create -f -
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata:
name: csr-controller
spec:
    groups:
    - system:authenticated
    request: $(cat server.csr | base64 | tr -d '\n')
    signerName: kubernetes.io/kubelet-serving
    usages:
    - digital signature
    - key encipherment
    - server auth
EOF
```

source : https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/certificate-signing-requests/

PS: I have tested it with Kubernetes version 1.21.3

Answer (score 0):

> How to create a `CertificateSigningRequest` with apiVersion
> `certificates.k8s.io/v1` for a webhook?

I have successfully created `certificates.k8s.io/v1` with the following issuers and openssl csr config. It was tested with [this webhook example](https://github.com/stackrox/admission-controller-webhook-demo).

Please check out the configs below:

```
#csr.conf
 
[req]
req_extensions = v3_req
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
[req_distinguished_name]
[ v3_req ]
basicConstraints = CA:FALSE
keyUsage = nonRepudiation, digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
extendedKeyUsage = clientAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS.1 = ${service}
DNS.2 = ${service}.${namespace}
DNS.3 = ${service}.${namespace}.svc
```

and:

```
#csr-for-webhook.yaml
 
apiVersion: certificates.k8s.io/v1
kind: CertificateSigningRequest
metadata:
  name: ${csrName}
spec:
  groups:
  - system:authenticated
  request: $(cat ${tmpdir}/server.csr | base64 | tr -d '\n')
  usages:
  - digital signature
  - key encipherment
  - client auth
  signerName: kubernetes.io/kube-apiserver-client
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand how is this different from what I did? They both look the same to me.